# Who did White voters in California vote for in the 1984 U.S. Presidential Election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, data-sources, california, exit-polls

California exit poll 1984: https://ropercenter.cornell.edu/ipoll/study/31090659

I'm not able to download that exit poll myself, but if anyone here has access to it, does it show what percent of White voters in California voted for Reagan or Mondale in the 1984 election? I know the national exit poll says 66% of White voters nationwide voted for Reagan, while 34% voted for Mondale. But I'm curious to see what the numbers from California were, if they're available.

Answer (score 3):

A [Report referencing the CBS exit polls](https://openyls.law.yale.edu/bitstream/handle/20.500.13051/8934/37_105YaleLJ935_January1996_.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y) for 1984, 1988, and 1992 provides these numbers for California (and other states). But, note that, according to the footnote for the table shown, the numbers for 1984 and 1988 are estimates from the "national file" rather than the "California file".

[image: Table of exit poll results]

The footnote for the table says —

> 313. My calculations are based on data contained in GENERAL ELECTION EXIT POLL 1992, *supra* note 276 (California file) (surveying 1618 white voters, 264 black voters and 268 Hispanic voters); CBS NEWS EXIT POLL 1988, *supra* note 277 (national file) (surveying 856 white voters, 210 black voters and 102 Hispanic voters); CBS News EXIT POLL 1984, *supra* note 277 (national file) (surveying 693 white voters, 215 black voters and 121 Hispanic voters).
>      Asian-Americans were not included as a separate category in the 1984 or 1988 CBS general election polls. In 1992, Asian-Americans in California were split among the three candidates, with 39% voting for Clinton, 39% for Bush, and 22% for Perot. My calculations are based on data contained in GENERAL
>      ELECTION EXIT POLL 1992, *supra* note 276 (California file) (surveying 81 Asian-American voters).

Comment: Thanks so much! It's great that info is available. I wonder if there's info from previous elections, like 1972, 1976, 1980?